# Get menu link item from MenuLinkTreeElement

Tags: 8, navigation

Hey I am loading a drupal 8 menu in the following way:

```
if ($menu != NULL) {
    $tree = \Drupal::menuTree()
    ->load("my_menu", new MenuTreeParameters());
```

This returns MenuLinkTreeElement objects.
It does not seem possible to fetch the fields attached to the menu item.

How can I do that? Should I load the menu through another function?

Comment: `$element->link` should get you the entity which you can treat as any other wrt accessing field data

Comment: I am trying that..it returns a MenuLinkContent but...this I can not use this to get any fields. I would think that I could get the uuid load the menu link entity and from there get the fields but even that is not possible, because the getUuid() is protected https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21menu_link_content%21src%21Entity%21MenuLinkContent.php/class/MenuLinkContent/8.2.x

Comment: `MenuLinkContent` is a content entity type; you can access its fields the same way as a node/taxonomy term/etc. e.g. `$entity->field_foo->value`

Comment: I am trying to access the fields that I know for sure are there like title , but nothing comes back: $item->link->title->value

Comment: There are two `MenuLinkContent` classes, an entity and a plugin. But I don't know how to extract the entity or uuid from the plugin.

Comment: @4k4 `MenuLinkTreeElement::link` is an instance of `\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkInterface`, so it's an entity rather than plugin in this case

Comment: Actually it is my bad that I didn't post this before. It returns a plugin Drupal\menu_link_content\Plugin\Menu\MenuLinkContent

Comment: yes, and the entity is Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent, you can see it protected in the plugin, but can't access it

Comment: Yep my mistake, that interface is a plugin interface. Looks like you're out of luck @Potney. For the obvious fields you're covered, e.g. `$link->getTitle()`, but the interface doesn't expose the data you're looking for. Might be worth posting a feature request, or looking at how modules like https://www.drupal.org/project/link_attributes solve similar problems

Comment: @Clive, after going through the public methods I found the uuid, see the answer.

Comment: Good find @4k4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the menu link content entity by accessing the uuid with the method `getDerivativeId()` of the plugin:

```
if ($link instanceof \Drupal\menu_link_content\Plugin\Menu\MenuLinkContent) {
  $uuid = $link->getDerivativeId();
  $entity = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')
    ->loadEntityByUuid('menu_link_content', $uuid);
  $field_value = $entity->field_example->value;
}
```

Comment: `EntityManager` was deprecated, [`EntityRepository::loadEntityByUuid()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityRepository.php/function/EntityRepository%3A%3AloadEntityByUuid/8.2.x#comment-62567) seems to be a good alternative

Comment: I remember I've checked this when writing the answer. Back then it was not used directly in core, now it pops up a few times. It's time to change this.

Comment: This is so not-OO. There is a `getEntity()` function on `\Drupal\menu_link_content\Plugin\Menu\MenuLinkContent` but it is protected.

Comment: @EricMORAND, there is already a follow-up question, see the linked question.

Comment: MenuLinkContent's getEntity() method is public now (when Drupal 10.2.0 is released). See https://www.drupal.org/node/3361300