# How to add a field to menus?

Tags: forms, hooks, navigation

I am trying to add an extra text field to the menu entity. My field is showing up and saving input but the input saves for all menus not just the one I entered the data for.

This is how it is now:

```
function myModule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'menu_edit_form') {
    $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('myModule.settings');
    $my_field = $config->get('my_field');
    $form['my_field'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title'),
    '#default_value' => $my_field,
    '#weight' => '0',
    '#required' => FALSE,
    );

    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'myModule_menu_edit_submit';
  }
}

function myModule_menu_edit_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('myModule.settings');
  $config->set('my_field', $form_state->getValue('my_field'))->save();
}
```

I need to save different data for each form, so I was trying to do change the submit function to:

```
function myModule_menu_edit_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $key = $form_state->getformObject()->getEntity()->id();
  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('myModule.settings');
  $config->set($key, $form_state->getValue('my_field'))->save();
}
```

If I do this though, when I enter the data in the field and save, it says updated successfully but the field is blank. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There is a module for that(TM)  - https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_extras

Comment: Did you install the module or re-install if already installed? By the way, using the field is not so easy because the menu link entity is behind a menu link plugin which has methods only for the standard fields. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235754/get-menu-link-item-from-menulinktreeelement

Comment: @Hudri So I want to add the field to the actual menu where you add/edit the actual menu, not the menu links. Does that module work for my situation as well?

@4k4 I haven't tried reinstalling the module. Do you think making a ```hook_update_N``` and putting my code in that and then doing a ```drush updb``` would work?

Comment: The module is for menu links (this individual items below a menu). The menu itself is not a fieldable content entity, you can't add content fields there. A menu is a configuration entity, you only can add 3rd party config settings there.

Comment: Example for menu 3rd party setting: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/menu_trail_by_path/-/blob/8.x-1.x/menu_trail_by_path.module

Comment: @Hudri So I tried with hook_form_FORM_ID_alter before trying this method and the field did show up but I had no idea how to get the data input for the field to save/load.

Comment: @Hudri I updated my question. I got it working somewhat but not exactly as I need it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to add a field to the menus (not menu links, the actual menus). I use the machine name of the menu's title as a key and store the value with the key I use in the `$form` variable.

Here is my code:

```
function myModule_form_menu_edit_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('myModule.settings');
  $my_field = $config->get(str_replace('-', '_', $form_state->getformObject()->getEntity()->id()));

  $form['my_field'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Title'),
  '#default_value' => $my_field,
  '#weight' => '0',
  '#required' => FALSE,
  );

  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'myModule_custom_submit';
}

function myModule_custom_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $key = str_replace('-', '_', $form_state->getformObject()->getEntity()->id());
  $config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('myModule.settings');
  $config->set($key, $form_state->getValue('my_field'))->save();
}
```